# how to create a fake download link using html

Tags: html, css, laravel

i have a website to show some videos but how can i make these videos not downloadable , even if the user is using IDM or any other program ? , i have tried making an image over the video to avoid getting the link of the video but it didn't help so can anyone help me ?
and that's my view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>video</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="video-thumbnail">
<div class="video-button">
<iframe class="video-embed" width="656" height="348" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kLgPkovrnJM?rel=0&color=white&controls=1&showinfo=0" s8011508427261248624="true" replaced="true"></iframe></div>
</div>
<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready( function(){
             $(".video-button").click(function(){
             $(".video-embed").css({"opacity":"1","display":"block"});
              $(".video-embed")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
              $(this).unbind("click");
            });
        } );
    })(jQuery)
</script>

</body>
```

and that's my css :

```
.embed-video {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: -1;
}

.video-button {
    background-image: url(images/video-cover.png);
    content: "";
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 348px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 656px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.video-thumbnail {
    height: 348px;
    position: relative;
    width: 656px;
}

.video-embed {
    display: none;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: How do you include the video? which player do you use? where are your videos, on your server or you use some storage provider? this is a little too generic

Comment: i updated my question have a look @gbalduzzi

Comment: This is nearly impossible to prevent. Anything that you do with CSS or Javascript can simply be edited from the developer tools. Why do you need to prevent them downloading?

Comment: my boss wants that

Comment: @James so isn't there anyway to do it even  manipulating the url ?

Comment: Not really. I could still use dev tools to monitor where the video is actually loaded from. You could make it tricky by generating a one off URL code that needs to be provided to download the video and so once it is loaded on your page it won't work to retrieve the video again - but even then using right click saving should still work.

Comment: okay thanks man (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to avoid users getting your video URL from the browser and no way to make impossible get a video you are already sending to the user in your webpage.

You can make things harder by adding some hacks (only thing i can think of is some server-side check to only allows requests from your webpage but there is always a way to fake the proper request) but you will never be 100% sure